# Passing arguments to a popup with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The idea is to have a list of items and once you click one of them, a popup appears with this information so you can update the item.

I created the popup following this page:

http://istockphp.com/jquery/creating-popup-div-with-jquery/

And I used it with a list, instead of a simple text like this:

```
    <c:forEach items="${meetings}" var="meeting">
        <li class="list1">
                    <a href="MeetingManagement?id=${meeting.getId()}" class="topopup">${meeting.getDate()}</a>
                    (<c:out value="${meeting.getType()}"/>) 
                    <c:out value="${meeting.stringMeetingLeader}"/><br>
            </li>
    </c:forEach>
```

So, how can I access the meeting info from the popup?

Comment: Create a javascript method with parameters as required and call on anchor click, and in that method add logic for opening poup.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add the meeting info to data-* attributes on the anchor, i.e.

```
<a href="MeetingManagement?id=${meeting.getId()}" data-time="[meeting time]" data-title=[metting-title] class="topopup">${meeting.getDate()}</a>
```

You would of course need to replace the [...] with the correct information populated from php or wherever.  You could then use jQuery's .data() method to retrieve that information when constructing the popup.  More on the data method at http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2

Comment: No problem, data-* attributes are really handy for stuff like what you described!

Comment: well, i've been trying several things in here, but i have no idea how to use the .data() method...

i debugg the web and it shows this:
<div class="content">
<h2 class="sidebar1">Meetings</h2>
<li class="list1">
<a href="MeetingManagement?id=13" data-id="13" class="topopup">2013-02-25</a>
(SprintPlanning)
<br>
</li>
<li class="list1">
<a href="MeetingManagement?id=8" data-id="8" class="topopup">2013-02-11</a>
(SprintReview)
<br>
</li>
...
</li>
( "X" ).data("id"), which X?

Comment: It depends on where you are putting your additional script, but if you are adding to the $('a.topopup').click you could use $(this).data('id')

Comment: and how can i make it available for the other div section? can i set some attributes on the request?

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean by the other dive section.

Comment: i have a <div id="contentResultsTable"> .... </div> section, where i have a list of the meetings, whenever i click one, the popup appears, i have some jquery:
$("a.topopup").click(function() {
   var selectedID = $(this).data('id');
....});
and i need that "selectedID" variable to be used in this other <div id="toPopup">...</div> that it's display once the meeteng has been selected

Comment: Can't you just put it in the div the same way you put it in the anchor?

Comment: i'm too lost in this jquery stuff, so i went to the window.open function, thanks for your help anyway :)

Comment: No worries, glad you figured out something that worked.